# jQuery gallery turn over with next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, xhtml

i'm trying to do some kind of Gallery-Turn Over Script with jQuery. Therefor i got an array with - let's say 13 - images:

```
galleryImages = new Array(
'images/tb_01.jpg',
'images/tb_02.jpg',
'images/tb_03.jpg',
'images/tb_04.jpg',
'images/tb_05.jpg',
'images/tb_06.jpg',
'images/tb_07.jpg',
'images/tb_08.jpg',
'images/tb_09.jpg',
'images/tb_10.jpg',
'images/tb_11.jpg',
'images/tb_12.jpg',
'images/tb_13.jpg'
);
```

My gallery looks like a grid showing only 9 images at once. My current script already counts the number of li-elements in #gallery, loads the first 9 images and displays them. The HTML looks like this:

```
<ul id="gallery">
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>

<ul id="gallery-controls">
    <li id="gallery-prev"><a href="#">Previous</a></li>
    <li id="gallery-next"><a href="#">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

I'm pretty new to jQuery an my problem is that i can't figure out how to split the array in portions with 9 elements to attach it as a link on the control buttons. I need something like this:

```
$('#gallery-next').click(function(){
    $('ul#gallery li').children().remove();
    $('ul#gallery li').each(function(index,el){
        var img = new Image();
        $(img).load(function () {
            $(this).css('display','none');
            $(el).append(this);
            $(this).fadeIn();
        }).attr('src', galleryImages[index]); //index for the next 9 images?!?!
    });
});
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#gallery-prev, #gallery-next{text-decoration:underline;color:Blue;cursor:pointer;list-style:none;display:inline;padding:5px;}
#gallery li{list-style:none;display:inline;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
  galleryImages = new Array(
    'images/tb_01.jpg','images/tb_02.jpg','images/tb_03.jpg',
    'images/tb_04.jpg','images/tb_05.jpg','images/tb_06.jpg',
    'images/tb_07.jpg','images/tb_08.jpg','images/tb_09.jpg',
    'images/tb_10.jpg','images/tb_11.jpg','images/tb_12.jpg',
    'images/tb_13.jpg');

  function loadImages(p) {
    var startIndex = parseInt($('ul#gallery').attr("startIndex")) + 9 * p;
    if (startIndex < 1 || startIndex >= galleryImages.length) return;

    $('ul#gallery')
    .attr('startIndex', startIndex)
    .find("li").children().remove().end()
    .each(function(i, el) {
      var nextID = startIndex - 1 + i;
      if (nextID >= 0 && nextID < galleryImages.length) {
        $(this).append($("<img src='" + galleryImages[nextID] + "' alt='image " + (nextID + 1) + "' />"));
      }
    });
  }

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul#gallery').attr('startIndex', '1');

    for (var i = 1; i <= 9; i++) 
      $('ul#gallery').append("<li></li>");

    loadImages(0);
    $('li#gallery-prev, li#gallery-next').each(function(i) {
      $(this).click(function() {
          loadImages(i == 1 ? 1 : -1); 
      }) 
    });
  });

</script>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="gallery"></ul>
<ul id="gallery-controls">
    <li id="gallery-prev">Previous</li>
    <li id="gallery-next">Next</li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out my [solution to your problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CaK3c/).

A few important notes:

1. I've changes the way your buttons work from a list to two spans.
2. I moved the line `$(el).append(img)` to a more appropriate spot.
3. The `curIndex` is the index of the last most image.
4. To get the next index image, I used `curIndex+index`, and then modded it by galleryImages.length so that it will loop the overflow rather than giving errors.
5. You **cannot** actually see the images (for obvious reasons), so I have added the index as text in each `<li>` so you can see with is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a variable, say `var firstIndex = 0;` to hold the array index of the first image currently displayed. Have your "next" button increment it and your "previous" button decrement it as necessary (by 1 or 9 or how you want). Add this value to `index` in your code.

Naturally you will need to check array bounds.