# jquery previous and next button in image gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a simple image gallery

http://jsfiddle.net/QEh53/1/

Imgs array can store upto 36 images and i wants to display only first 6 onload. there is one next and back button, I need it when click on Next it will show next 6 images from Imgs array and on clicking Back last 6 images should slide in. if there is no img left in prev or next it should loop through next 6 images.

Thank you for any help.

Edit:

I have tried this with just back button but for some reason it is not removing old list before adding new one http://jsfiddle.net/QEh53/6/

Edit:

here was solution:
[jQuery gallery turn over with next and previous buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715615/jquery-gallery-turn-over-with-next-and-previous-buttons)

Comment: This doesn't appear to be us offering 'help,' but seems more like us 'doing this for you.' What have you tried, and where are you stuck? What problems are you having?

Comment: here is exact code I have wrote now http://jsfiddle.net/QEh53/1/ but I m not sure how can i split it to display 6 images with next/back button.

Comment: I have tried this with just back button but for some reason it is not removing old list before adding new one http://jsfiddle.net/QEh53/6/  and apologize I am new to JavaScript and learning at my own..

Answer (score 0):

I belive this code will help you: [example.js](http://orlleite.com/code/exemplo.js)

`total` is the amount of "pages", you can set it as `Math.ceil( totalImages / 6 )`.

This, nonstopping pages was called `loop` in that code. It returns a correct page, as you wanted.

```
function loop( value )
{
    return value < 0 ? total + value : ( value >= total ? value % total : value );
}
```

Comment: never mind found solution here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715615/jquery-gallery-turn-over-with-next-and-previous-buttons thank you